# How to invoke member function safely when inheriting std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

My code is as below:

```
  class MyThread : public std::thread {
        int a_;

    public:
        MyThread(int a)
            : std::thread(&MyThread::run, this),
              a_(a)
        { }

        void run() {
            // use a_
        }
    };
```

I want to have my own thread class which has all the methods that std::thread provides, so I let MyThread class inherit std::thread.
In MyThread's constructor, I pass its member function to std::thread. The compilation is OK, but I am concerned it there a race condition between invoking run() in std::thread's construtor and initializing a_.

Is there a way to make it safe?

Comment: `which has all the methods that std::thread provides` Which methods are you referring to exactly? You do not need to inherit to access the public member functions. Accessing protected member functions and variables could be a case but I don't know of any.

Comment: @TrickorTreat, methods like join() or get_id(). I don't want to add these interfaces again in MyThread by composing and adapting a std::thread object, so I subclass std::thread directly.

Answer (score 3):

Don't do it that way.  "Has-a" (composition) has a lot of advantages over "is-a" (inheritance).

```
class MyThread
{
    std::thread _thread;
    int _a;
public:

    MyThread(int a) : _a(a)
    {
        _thread = std::thread([this] {run();});
    }

    void run()
    {
       // thread code here
    };

    void join()
    {
        _thread.join();
    }
};
```

A better approach would be to recognize that the thread and the operation on that thread are two distinct objects:

```
class WorkerOperation
{
    int _a;
public:
   WorkerOperation(int a) :  _a(a)
   {
   }

   void run()
   {
     // your code goes here
   }
};
```

And then to create a thread:

```
shared_ptr<WorkerOperation> spOp = make_shared<WorkerOperation>(42);
std::thread t = std::thread([spOp] {spOp->run();});
```

And if you really need to pair up the operation and the thread:

```
std::pair<WorkerOperation, std::thread> threadpair;
threadpair.first = spOp;
threadpair.second = std::move(t);
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix the error you can write:

```
    MyThread(int a)
        :a_(a)
    { 
        (std::thread&)(*this) = std::thread(&MyThread::run, this);
     }
```

This way, the thread is run with initialized `a_`.

In general, I don't think it is a good idea to inherit from std::thread. Better make it a private member and run it. Otherwise user can do weird shit if you allow them to cast your class to std::thread& publicly. Like executing a different function than what you intended.

Comment: Well, this might be a workaround after adding an override of  MyThread& operator=(std::thread&&). Thanks @alx23z

Answer (score 0):

> but I am concerned it there a race condition between invoking run() in std::thread's construtor and initializing a_.

Yes,

You might reorder member/base:

```
struct MyThreadData
{
    int _a;
};

struct MyThread : MyThreadData, std::thread
{
public:
   explicit MyThread(int a) : MyThreadData{a}, _thread([this] {run();}) {}

    void run()
    {
       // thread code here
    };
};
```